# how to detect staircase using open cv python?

Tags: python, opencv, object-recognition

I am presently working on a project based on blind man navigation. I need to detect staircases for that project. Can anyone help with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Basically all you need to do is to create a training set (a set of images that contain staircases and a set of image that do not contain staircases), train you model and predict. This is really basically all you have to do. More precisely you can look [here](http://blog.yhat.com/posts/image-classification-in-Python.html) or [here](http://www.intorobotics.com/how-to-detect-and-track-object-with-opencv/)